# Вставить картинку и текст через html в svg

Tags: html, svg

Доброй ночи!
Начал изучать верстку html через svg. сверстал вот такой макет

```css
.container1 {
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
}

svg {
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

.grey {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: grey;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.red {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: 1800 1800;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1800;
  animation: drawPath 5s linear forwards;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  animation: changeColor 1s linear forwards;
  z-index: 2;
}

.circle1 {
  top: 160px;
  left: 5px;
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

.circle2 {
  top: 210px;
  left: 267px;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

.circle.circle3 {
  top: 65px;
  left: 353px;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.circle.circle4 {
  top: 160px;
  left: 523px;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

.circle.circle5 {
  top: 380px;
  left: 650px;
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}

@keyframes drawPath {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  to {
    background: red;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="circle circle1"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="circle circle2"><i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="circle circle3"><i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="circle circle4"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div class="circle circle5"><i class="fa fa-rocket" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>


  <svg width="1200" height="800" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <symbol id="hexagon">
                <polyline points="90,5 175,55 175,155 90,205 5,155 5,55 90,5" class="grey"/>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="hexagonb">
                <polyline points="135,5 265,80 265,230 135,305 5,230 5,80 135,5" class="grey"/>
            </symbol>
            <use xlink:href="#hexagon" x="5" y="105"/>
            <use xlink:href="#hexagonb" x="45" y="256"/>
            <use xlink:href="#hexagon" x="270" y="160" />
            <use xlink:href="#hexagon" x="355" y="10" />
            <use xlink:href="#hexagonb" x="525" y="85" />

            <polyline points="10,160 95,110 180,160 180,261 275,315 275,215 360,165 360,65 445,15 530,65 530,165 660,90 790,165 790,315 660,390" class="red"/>
        </svg>
</div>
```

Теперь стоит задача вставить текст и картинку как на картинке ниже 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите вариант?

Comment: Когда шаблоны закончились в интернете...